# Problem with iterating over two lists simultaneously

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1. I have written some code like the following and now I want to get the result of these two queries that has the same size and iterate over each one of them and divide their element and store  the result in a list. But now the problem is in my zip method, I can not specify exactly which attribute of each query I want to divide.

```
var mytotal = _context.Apiapp.GroupBy(o => new
        {
            Month = o.ApiRequestDate.Substring(4, 2),
            Year = o.ApiRequestDate.Substring(0, 4)
        }).Select(g => new
        {
            Month = g.Key.Month,
            Year = g.Key.Year,
            Total = g.Count()
        }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Year).ThenByDescending(a => a.Month).ToList();

var numerator =  from t1 in _context.Apiapp
                 join t2 in _context.ApiAppHistory on t1.Id equals t2.ApiApplicantId
                 join t3 in _context.EntityType on t2.LastReqStatus equals t3.Id
                 where t1.IsDeleted == false && t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id && t3.Name == "granted"
                 group new { Year = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(0, 4), Month = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(4, 2) }
                         by new { t2.LastReqStatus } into g
                 select new
                         {
                             Year = g.Max(n => n.Year),
                             Month = g.Max(n => n.Month),
                             GrantedCount = g.Count()
                         };
var GrantedReqStatus = numerator.ToList();
var GrantedAccessPercent = new List<Double>();

//-------------------------------------------------------
var res = mytotal.Zip(GrantedReqStatus, (total, GrantedCount) => new { Num = total, Denum = GrantedCount });

foreach(var r in res)
{
    GrantedAccessPercent.Add(r.Num/r.Denum);
}
```

Here inside the body of foreach, r.Num and r.Denum is unknown! I appreciate of any help to fix the error.

Comment: Your code is really hard to read. Why are you mixing LINQ query syntax? Why are you querying the Apiapp table twice instead of just once? Why are some variable names capitalized? Can you post a simpler question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Num` and `DemNum` in the `Zip` function represent objects for the first and second collection, that contains `Month`,`Year` and `Total` for the `total` object and `Month`,`Year` and `GrantedCount` for the `grantedCount` object.
You could use `total.Total` and `grantedCount.GrantedCount` to get numbers, like the following code:

```
var res = mytotal.Zip(GrantedReqStatus, (total, grantedCount) => new { Num = total.Total, Denum = grantedCount.GrantedCount });

foreach(var r in res)
{
    GrantedAccessPercent.Add(Math.Round(r.Num / (double)r.DemNum, 2));
}
```

Note that, to divide `int1/int2` you need to cast `int2` to `double`, Will give the expected result, and you can use also `Math.Round` to specify numbers after comma.

I hope this help you fix the issue.